# JSON fetch and push from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, objective-c, json

I'm getting good at basic iOS applications and stuff, and want to take it up a notch! I've created my server with php/mysql and that is up and running.

**Now I already know these things:**

*Basic UML:*

```
iOS app -Fetch to- api.php -Fetch to- mysql database (And in reverse)
```

So the iOS app sends a GET to the `api.php?hello=world` and the api fetches the data, converts it to JSON and sends it back to the iOS app.

**Please correct me if I am wrong.**

**Now some questions:**

- In an advanced app, will the `api.php?hello=world` be encrypted and decrypted by the api.php? So if there would be a man in the middle or someone sniffing, it couldn't see i'm asking `hello` for `world`?
- Is there any other stuff I need to know, or any handy tutorial for security with passing data trough these channels?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In an advanced app, will the api.php?hello=world be encrypted and decrypted by the api.php? So if there would be a man in the middle or someone sniffing, it couldn't see i'm asking hello for world?

If you're concerned about security, I would suggest using SSL on your API server

> Is there any other stuff I need to know, or any handy tutorial for security with passing data trough these channels?

You can implement OAuth for authenication.

Comment: Oke thanks! I'm going to try the SSL first, and look into OAuth.